# API jQuery AJAX load time double Browser load time

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a page that is loading a few AJAX GET requests in parallel and sequence.  The source is a local server for testing.

I opened chrome inspector to review how long each request is taking.  One of them is consistently ~1.5 sec.  However, when I right click on the URL in inspector and open the link in a new tab it consistently takes ~500ms.

There is some serious latency here from the AJAX request.

How can I diagnose and improve these AJAX requests?

Comment: I am able to replicate this with some popular websites, but the response time difference isn't so drastic.